# Retain remote image dimensions in Outlook HTML Signatures

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, email-signature

I'm using an image (96DPI) from a remote server in my Outlook signature named banner.png. I don't specify the image height and width attributes in my HTML code. This is so that I may change the size and content of banner.png at will without having to rework the code. Now, suppose banner.png on the remove server is 100px x 100px, the signature is displayed ok. But if I were to change the size of banner.png on the server to 11ppx x 200px, the image is resized by outlook and looks awful.

Is there anyhow I can prevent Outlook from resizing the remote image when it renders it?

Cheers